# Saving to a many to many relationship

Tags: entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

The problem am facing is, anytime I call events.Tags.Add(tag) and call Save changes on the context, it ends up creating a new tag info in the Tags table instead of just inserting the EventId and TagId into just the EventTags Table.

Base on the data below how do I add an event and tag into the EventTags Table. Lets say I want to add Event with Id=2 and and tag with Id =1 to the EventTags table.

I have the following entities.

```
 public class Event
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }  
        public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    }


    public class Tag
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
    }

      public class EventConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Event> {
            public  EventConfiguration () {
                ToTable("Events");
                HasKey(x => x.Id).Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("Id").IsRequired();
                Property(x => x.Name).HasColumnName("Name").IsRequired();

      HasMany(x => x.Tags)
                   .WithMany(x => x.Events)
                   .Map(m => {
                       m.ToTable("EventTags");
                       m.MapLeftKey("EventId");
                       m.MapRightKey("TagId");
                   });
            }
        }


    public class TagConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Tag> {
            public  TagConfiguration () {
                ToTable("Tags");
                HasKey(x => x.Id).Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("Id").IsRequired();
                Property(x => x.Name).HasColumnName("Name").IsRequired();
            }
        }



/*
These are the records in my many to many tables

--------------

Events Table

--------------

Id  Name

1   Test1

2   Test2



--------------

EventTags

-------------

EventId TagId

1       2



-------------

Tags

------------

Id  Name

1   MVC

2   C#
*/
```

Comment: post your add code - is the tag you are adding fetched from the same DBContext ?

Answer (score 0):

> Lets say I want to add Event with Id=2 and and tag with Id =1 to the
>   EventTags table.

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    // Load the event
    var theEvent = context.Events.Find(2);
    // Load the tag       
    var theTag = context.Tags.Find(1);

    // Add tag to Tags collection of the event
    theEvent.Tags.Add(theTag);

    // Save
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

It's enough to update one of the two collections. EF takes care of the other collection automatically.

**Edit**

Another option without loading the entities from the DB if you know the existing Ids:

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    // Create an event with Id 2
    var theEvent = new Event { Id = 2, Tags = new HashSet<Tag>() };
    // Create a tag with Id 1
    var theTag = new Tag { Id = 1 };

    // Attach both event and tag to the context
    context.Events.Attach(theEvent);
    context.Tags.Attach(theTag);

    // Add tag to Tags collection of the event
    theEvent.Tags.Add(theTag);

    // Save
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

You can also mix both approaches, for example load event from DB, create and attach the tag.